# Convert SQL QUERY to LINQ TO ENTITIES

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I wont to select top 4 for operators   ( having max count in user table)

```
SELECT TOP 4  [Operator], COUNT(Operator) as opCount
  FROM [Users] 
  Group by Operator
  order by opCount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this.

```
var result = db.Users.Take(4).GroupBy(y=>y.Operator).ToList();
```